# cannot resolve symbol "LoadPreferences" , "nSharedPreferenceListener"

Tags: android

this is my main activity,actually i am trying to display the settings option by pressing the icon on the Action Bar , the settings option invokes the Preference options(the default values) . I am getting errors .
There are red marks on  "LoadPreferences" , "nSharedPreferenceListener"

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class LauncherActivity_StreamCameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

private SurfaceHolder nPreviewDisplay = null;


    private static final String TAG = LauncherActivity_StreamCameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String PREF_CAMERA = "camera";
    private static final int PREF_CAMERA_DEF = 0;
    private static final String PREF_FLASH_LIGHT = "flash_light";
    private static final boolean PREF_FLASH_LIGHT_DEF = false;
    private static final String PREF_PORT = "port";
    private static final int PREF_PORT_DEF = 8080;
    private static final String PREF_JPEG_SIZE = "size";
    private static final String PREF_JPEG_QUALITY = "jpeg_quality";
    private static final int PREF_JPEG_QUALITY_DEF = 40;
    // preview sizes will always have at least one element, so this is safe
    private static final int PREF_PREVIEW_SIZE_DEF = 0;

    private static final String WAKE_LOCK_TAG = "wicam";
    private PowerManager.WakeLock nWakeLock = null;
    private boolean nRunning = false;
    private SharedPreferences nPrefs = null;
    private boolean nPreviewDisplayCreated = false;
    private Activity2_1CameraStream nCameraStream = null;
    private int nCameraIndex = PREF_CAMERA_DEF;
    private boolean nUseFlashLight = PREF_FLASH_LIGHT_DEF;
    private int nPort = PREF_PORT_DEF;
    private int nJpegQuality = PREF_JPEG_QUALITY_DEF;
    private int nPreviewSizeIndex = PREF_PREVIEW_SIZE_DEF;

    private MenuItem nSettingsMenuItem = null;

    private TextView nIpAddressView = null;
    private String nIpAddress = "";

    public LauncherActivity_StreamCameraActivity() {super();}    // constructor()

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        new LoadPreferences().execute();
        nPreviewDisplay = ((SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.Camera)).getHolder();
        nPreviewDisplay.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        nPreviewDisplay.addCallback(this);
        nIpAddress = tryGetIpv4address();
        nIpAddressView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ipaddress);
        updateCacheAndUi();

        final PowerManager powermanager =
                (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        nWakeLock = powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK,
                WAKE_LOCK_TAG);


    }// onCreate(Bundle

    @Override


    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        nRunning = true;
        if (nPrefs != null)
        {
            nPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                    nSharedPreferenceListener);
        } // if
        updateCacheAndUi();
        tryStartCameraStream();
        nWakeLock.acquire();
    } // onResume()

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        nWakeLock.release();
        super.onPause();
        nRunning = false;
        if (nPrefs != null)
        {
            nPrefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                    nSharedPreferenceListener);
        } // if
        ensureCameraStreamStopped();
    } // onPause()


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder holder, final int format,
                               final int width, final int height)
    {
        // Ingored
    } // surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder, int, int, int)

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        nPreviewDisplayCreated = true;
        tryStartCameraStream();
    } // surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder)

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        nPreviewDisplayCreated = false;
        ensureCameraStreamStopped();
    } // surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder)

    private void tryStartCameraStream()
    {
        if (nRunning && nPreviewDisplayCreated && nPrefs != null)
        {
            nCameraStream = new Activity2_1CameraStream(nCameraIndex, nUseFlashLight, nPort,
                    nPreviewSizeIndex, nJpegQuality, nPreviewDisplay);
            nCameraStream.start();
        } // if
    } // tryStartCameraStreamer()

    private void ensureCameraStreamStopped()
    {
        if (nCameraStream != null)
        {
            nCameraStream.stop();
            nCameraStream = null;
        } // if
    } // stopCameraStreamer()

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       /* nSettingsMenuItem = menu.add(R.string.settings);
        nSettingsMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);
        */
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    } // onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
    {
        /*if (item != nSettingsMenuItem)
        {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } // if
        */
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2_2PreferenceActivityScreen.class));
        return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } // onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)

    private final class LoadPreferences
            extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SharedPreferences>
    {
        private LoadPreferences()
        {
            super();
        } // constructor()

        @Override
        protected SharedPreferences doInBackground(final Void... noParams)
        {
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    LauncherActivity_StreamCameraActivity.this);
        } // doInBackground()

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final SharedPreferences prefs)
        {
            LauncherActivity_StreamCameraActivity.this.nPrefs = prefs;
            prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                    nSharedPreferenceListener);
            updateCacheAndUi();
            tryStartCameraStream();
        } // onPostExecute(SharedPreferences)


    } // class LoadPreferences
    private final SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener nSharedPreferenceListener =
            new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences prefs,
                                                      final String key)
                {
                    updateCacheAndUi();
                } // on                SharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences, String)

            }; // nSharedPreferencesListener


    private final int getPrefInt(final String key, final int defValue)
    {
        // We can't just call getInt because the preference activity
        // saves everything as a string.
        try
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(nPrefs.getString(key, null /* defValue */));
        } // try
        catch (final NullPointerException e)
        {
            return defValue;
        } // catch
        catch (final NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return defValue;
        } // catch
    } // getPrefInt(String, int)

    private final void updateCacheAndUi()   //validation
    {
        nCameraIndex = getPrefInt(PREF_CAMERA, PREF_CAMERA_DEF);
        if (hasFlashLight())
        {
            if (nPrefs != null)
            {
                nUseFlashLight =nPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_FLASH_LIGHT,
                        PREF_FLASH_LIGHT_DEF);
            } // if
            else
            {
                nUseFlashLight = PREF_FLASH_LIGHT_DEF;
            } // else
        } //if
        else
        {
            nUseFlashLight = false;
        } // else

        // XXX: This validation should really be in the preferences activity.
        nPort = getPrefInt(PREF_PORT, PREF_PORT_DEF);
        // The port must be in the range [1024 65535]
        if (nPort < 1024)
        {
            nPort = 1024;
        } // if
        else if (nPort > 65535)
        {
            nPort = 65535;
        } // else if

        nPreviewSizeIndex = getPrefInt(PREF_JPEG_SIZE, PREF_PREVIEW_SIZE_DEF);
        nJpegQuality = getPrefInt(PREF_JPEG_QUALITY, PREF_JPEG_QUALITY_DEF);
        // The JPEG quality must be in the range [0 100]
        if (nJpegQuality < 0)
        {
            nJpegQuality = 0;
        } // if
        else if (nJpegQuality > 100)
        {
            nJpegQuality = 100;
        } // else if
        nIpAddressView.setText("http://" + nIpAddress + ":" + nPort + "/");
    } // updateCacheAndUi()


    private boolean hasFlashLight()
    {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    } // hasFlashLight()

    private static String tryGetIpv4address()
    {
        try
        {
            final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en =
                    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (en.hasMoreElements())
            {
                final NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                final Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr =
                        intf.getInetAddresses();
                while (enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    final  InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
                    {
                        final String addr = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                        if (InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(addr))
                        {
                            return addr;
                        }
                    } // if
                } // while
            } // for
        } // try
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            // Ignore
        } // catch
        return null;
    } // tryGetIpv4address()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that LoadPreferences is not found, the constructor is private.

Why don't you try to remove the:

```
private LoadPreferences()
{
     super();
}
```

And why is it "final"???

```
private final class LoadPreferences
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code (creating a fake main.xml for the resources and a fake Activity2_1CameraStream class) and my AndroidStudio doesn't show me any error. When you mean "there are red marks on LoadPrefererence and nSharedPreferenceListener", what do you exactly mean? Do you mean the constructor for LoadPreference cannot be called? Does it mean the class gives an error??